Identify Movie: Wife Comes Back After Car Crash for Revenge
I'm looking for a movie that I saw only once and can't recall what the title was, the only things I remember are this details:

A couple marries and live somewhere in the desert.
After a while the wife has a car crash and ends up disfigured.
The husband was the one who ordered the "accident".
After that the wifes returns with other face, seduces him again and then has her revenge.

Character Details

45 years old
Dark blonde hair
Skinny

I think the movie is from the 90s, but not very sure. It wasn't animated, and pretty sure it is a film from the United States. The title had something like paradise on it, but not sure either.
I know these are some vague details, but I'm scratching my head and Google isn't able to help me.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year or release and country\language? The actors or what they looked like?

I think the movie is from the 90s, but not very sure :/

Please add more details as per our ID question requirements, they can be found here:  http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Sure it was a movie, and not an episode from a series (similar to Twilight Zone)?  I've seen variations of that plot line as part of series or anthology movies.

Almost certain it was a moive

If you found the answer yourself, you can answer your own question, preferably elaborating in which way it fits to the details from the question.

After a sudden recovery of memory, I know which one it is. Is a miniseries called Return to Eden, and it wasn't a car crash, it were crocodriles. They do live in a desert, and the other details are also correct.
The miniseries is of the late 80's. The word in the title isn't paradise, it's Eden.
